# Excel function needed for assigning tasks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a formula in Excel that allows to distribute values in succession like this : There are 10 (A to J) employees in a company and they need to occupy 3 functions in the company (alpha, beta and gamma).
They need to work as follows:

```
A-> Alpha
B-> Beta
C-> Gamma
D-> Alpha
E-> Beta...
```

And so on.
There is an order that needs to be followed and Excel should help not to mess up the turns. Is there such a formula?

Comment: Please explain your question a bit further; what is it that you need, what did you try and why is/isn't that working?
The way you are posing the question now it would seem you can just put in Alpha, Beta, Gamma and let excel extend these 3 values..

Comment: To be more clear, there are much more tasks and much more employees. My problem is that the tasks have different difficulties, and i want to keep employees from complaining that they get for example two difficult tasks successively, and that others get easier tasks. In other words, I want to assign tasks automatically so that one employee starts with a certain task and gets to do the same task only after doing all the other tasks in an order that I will specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your list of names starts in A1.  You could use the following formula to loop through the numbers 1 to 3 and repeat as the formula is copied down:

```
=MOD(ROW(A1)-1,3)+1
```

Then based on the value 1 to 3 you could either use a VLOOKUP or CHOOSE to convert the 1-3 to a corresponding string.  To eliminate the helper column, embed the counting formula into the VLOOKUP or CHOOSE function.

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,$F$1:$G$3,2,0)
or
=CHOOSE(B1,"Alpha","Beta","Gamma")
```

[image: POC]

Combined option to eliminate the need for column B:

```
=CHOOSE(MOD(ROW(A1)-1,3)+1,"Alpha","Beta","Gamma")
```

Comment: If Column `F` is just `1`, `2`, `3`, it makes more sense to use `INDEX` (rather than `VLOOKUP`).

Comment: index is another rout to go as well.  Only felt like covering so many options

Comment: OK. Thank you for answering, but I think I may have asked my question the wrong way. You see, you may assume that there is an equivalent number of tasks and employees, so that no employee will have no task to perform.
So, the list has to be somehow like this:

Comment: Day1 A-> Alpha B-> Beta   C-> Gamma D-> Delta     E-> Tetha F-> Phi
Day2 A-> Phi     B-> Alpha  C->  Beta    D-> Gamma  E-> Delta  F-> Tetha...
And so on.

Answer (score 0):

If the order is a static, repeated list of Alpha, Beta, or Gamma then you can fill in the top three rows with their respective values, select the cells, then drag the green box in the bottom-right corner (or double-click) the selection down the list. Excel will copy the series down the list automatically.

[image: Example of fill series]